# How can I docker-build with Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I building docker image. But it does not success.

`/Users/username/.vim` exists on my host os, But it does not success.
How I can success docker- build?

Error Message:

```
Step 16 : ADD /Users/username/.vim/ /root/.vim
lstat Users/username/.vim/: no such file or directory
```

The following is my Dockerfile.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER MyName
RUN /bin/bash
RUN mkdir ~/cworks
RUN mkdir ~/pyworks
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get -y install clang
RUN apt-get -y install man
RUN apt-get -y install vim
RUN apt-get -y install python3
RUN apt-get -y install git
RUN apt-get -y install make
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN curl -kL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
ADD /Users/username/.vim/ /root/.vim
ADD /Users/username/.vimrc /root/.vimrc
```

Platform: OS X 10.11.4

Comment: It is recommended to use COPY instead of ADD (except in some specific instance). Have a look at this blog:
https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-add-vs-copy/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot execute ADD (or COPY) on a file that is not inside the directory that contains your Dockerfile.

The reason for that is that building docker images is meant to be a deterministic build. If I build the Dockerimage on my computer with your Dockerfile, I would have a different .vim
The docker team impose this limitation to encourage people using a self contained directory with a Dockerfile, and any file to add to it.

In your case, you will need to copy the file in the same directory of the Dockerfile first, and run:

```
ADD .vim /root/.vim
```

Or arguably better:

```
COPY .vim /root/.vim
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this form instead. It works with hidden files(dot files) and filename contains whitespaces.

```
ADD ["/Users/username/.vim/", "/root/.vim"]
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/add

Answer (score -1):

Please remove tailing slash after `.vim`

So, it will go as

`ADD /Users/username/.vim /root/.vim`

Comment: I removed slash, But the problem is not resolved yet.

Comment: Please using https://beta.docker.com/, it drop docker-machine and make docker more comfortable to use on OSX.